# Include variable identifier in histogram title in R

Tags: r, histogram, title

```
for (i in 1:8){
  hist(x, main="Histrogram i")
}
```

Is it possible to evaluate the variable i, so that I get 8 histograms titled "Histogram 1", "Histogram 2", ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to construct the character strings using `paste`.

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (i in 1:4) {
  hist(rnorm(100), main = paste("Histogram", i))
}
```

[image]